# Startup Tomcat Using Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

is it possible to have a grunt task that can startup tomcat on my local machine? I want to be able to use livereload for our project but I need 2 things: tomcat started on port 8080 and livereload to be watching on 8080. Hope this is possible and makes sense.

Thank you,

Rob

Comment: Tomcat is capable of this without the need for grunt. The feature is called autoDeploy or hot deploy. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to start up tomcat.